# jQuery load() replacing whole page instead of loading content into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load in thumbnail of an inputted webpage when the user clicks a button. The thumbnail is generated properly on the page by itself, but when I attempt to load it into the div element, it replaces the whole page. Currently, this is just a proof of concept. I will switch to user inputted url if I can get this working.

Here is my click event code:

```
$('#check_url').click(function() {
    $('#thumb_loader').load('load_thumb.html');
});
```

thumb_loader is just a div. I have also tried it like this:

```
$('#check_url').click(function() {
    $('#thumb_loader').html($('<div>').load('load_thumb.html'));
});
```

Here is load_thumb.html:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        wsr_snapshot('http://google.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Small');
    </script>
</div>
```

wsr_snashot is WebSnapr. The image is generated on their server and appears where this code is.

First off, can I even load javascript like this? I have used load to drop in content that contains javascript before, so I doubt that is the case.

Anyone see any problems here?

EDIT:

Here is the table where the div I wish to load into is and the button that the user would click to trigger the AJAX.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                    <div id="thumb_loader"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Link Title:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Link Description:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="link_title" />
                </td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    <textarea name="link_description"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Link URL:</label>
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="link_url" />
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="check_url" type="button" value="Check URL" />
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" /><input disabled="disabled" type="submit" value="Add Link" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I don't see anything else that could be relevant in the code. Hope this is enough.

Comment: Can you perhaps show more code for context, perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't put the site in jsfiddle, but I will add more code.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#thumb_loader').load('load_thumb.html div')` ?

Comment: Why can't u put the site in jsFiddle ? Put only the code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Ally This stopped it from replacing the entire page, but now only the div tag, not what was in the div tag, is there. :P

Comment: @Cristy, I do no know how to make that AJAX call to another file in jsfiddle. I can put the code there, but the other file goes where?

Comment: no. You can't execute js before it has been added to your page with your ajax call. My best guess is, that because the js is on the page already if it gets executed, WebSnapr replaces the full page.

Comment: about jsfiddle issue: upload your AJAX file to a random site and make an absolute URL to it in the AJAX call.

Comment: Does that `wsr_snapshot` do a document.write() ??? If it is then obviously it will take over the whole page !! Why dont u try that within an iframe, then when content is loaded inside that iframe get the contents from it into ur div.

Comment: @ahhchuu I just checked out the jQuery documentation. It's not loading the script because when you specify an element to insert (e.g. div in this case) it strips out any scripts contained in that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put JS code out of `load_thumb` file and keep in a new js file like `image.js` and use `$.getScript` to dynamically add it in your principal page:

```
$.getScript('path/image.js', function(){
   // file loaded
});
```

You should put above code in your main file where you want to run your thumb image.

More:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: This is perfect! I never knew this existed. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @11684 I was going to but the timer was not done counting down :P Why do people always forget there is a timer for new members.

Answer (score 1):

> [jQuery#load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/): When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

if `wsr_snapshot('http://google.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Small');` contains any `document.write` calls, you're entire document is overwritten. Make sure you know what that function does.

---

Update:

according to the question's comments, this really is the issue. You need to figure out how `wsr_snapshot()` can be used in an asynchronous fashion. What API is that from anyways?